# Can we add\attach security group to Terraform aws_cloudformation_stack resource

Tags: emr, aws-cloudformation, terraform

I am using Terraform to provision emr . In order to do so i am calling
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" and then attaching cloudformation template to launch an EMR. its working now i want my EMR to have 22 inbound port open for ssh connection.

please see reference 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html

i can do this by attaching a security group . could somebody please let me know how can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be able to handle this by creating the security group via Terraform, referencing it as a dependency to make sure it's created before the cloudformation stack and then providing the security group ID to the cloudformation template as a variable.

Comment: Cool, can you accept it as the correct answer? :) I think you might have just up-voted it.

Comment: oops yes . just did Thanks